# Подтвердите или опровергните

Tags: предлоги

В Украине - правило, на Украине - употребительная форма.

Comment: Правильно как раз ***на** Украине* (по-русски).

Comment: Вопрос закрыть как дубликат, а вопрошающего пороть розгами - пока волшебное слово "пожалуйста" не выучит.

Answer (score 0):

Это не "правило", а заимствованная из *украинского* языка форма (при ссылке на территорию, область, губернию), см. у Розенталя http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm :

> *Сочетание **на** Украину/Украйне возникло под влиянием **украинского** языка (ср.: на Полтавщину/Полтавщине, на Черниговщину/ Черниговщине) и
>   поддерживается выражением "на окраине".*

При ссылке на возникшее *государство* (поскольку оно *не островное*, к нему применим предлог "в") проявляются разногласия, основанные отчасти на привычности сочетания, применявшегося к внутренней *территории*, отчасти на неприятии частью носителей языка её отделения и превращения в *государство*. Поэтому дифференцированное употребление предлогов при ссылке на территорию (молодость провёл **на** Украине, **на** Брянщине, **на** Орловщине) и на государство (посол Никарагуа **в** Украине) принимается далеко не всеми - по *политическим* причинам.